# I am not able to list all the projects in my GCP organization using Python

Tags: python, gcloud, google-cloud-resource-manager

I need to list all projects under an Organization in GCP. I am using Resource Manager for the same.

```
def list_projects():
proj_list = []
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file('../key.json')
# Create resourcemanager_v3 ProjectsClient
resourcemanager_v3_projects_client = resourcemanager_v3.ProjectsClient(credentials=credentials)
#resourcemanager_v3_projects_client = resourcemanager_v3.ProjectsClient()
list_projects_request = resourcemanager_v3.ListProjectsRequest(show_deleted=False, parent='organizations/12345')
page_result = resourcemanager_v3_projects_client.list_projects(request=list_projects_request)

for response in page_result:
  proj_list.append(response.project_id)
```

The above Code skips all the projects under a Folder.
The Service Account running this code has **Organization Administrator** and **Folder Viewer** Roles.

Comment: You're not paging through results but, more importantly, I think you need to list the Folders at each level and then (recursively) enumerate the Projects that have each of the Folders as their parent. See: https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/listing-all-resources#list_all_resources_example